# Can I use s-pen hovering on a canvas?

Tags: android, hover, ellipsis, onhover

I have ellipsis labels (for e.g. "Sour...") drawn on canvas. Now how can I show the original string (in this case "Sourabh"), when I do S-Pen hovering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a Note 3 with Lollipop, it's super easy. Use the `:hover` statement (like desktop).
**NOTICE**: The `:hover` is also triggered when user touches the element.

```
.myelement:hover {
    content: "I hovered my S Pen over the element";
}
```